# Sylow subgroups of group of squarefree order

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Is there a way to prove that in a group of squarefree order Sylow subgroup corresponding to largest prime(which divides order of group) is normal without using transfer theory(and Burnside's theorem)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would make more sense to learn Burnside's Transfer Theorem than to spend time trying to avoid it.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but I want to know if this can be proven without that theorem.